# Create the hierarchical structure parent-child starting from string definition

Tags: c#

I have a list of object defined in the following way

```
public class MyObject
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Code { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

where the Id is the PK, and code contains a string made of numbers which defines the parent-child relationship between the objects:

```
id    |  Code      
1        10 15
2        10 15 10
3        10 15 20
4        10 15 30
5        10 15 30 10
6        10 15 30 20
7        10 20 
8        10 20 30
9        10 20 30 40
```

In the above example, object 1 is a root, 2,3,4 are children of 1; 5 and 6 are children of 4; 7 is a root; 8 is a child of 7 and 9 is a child of 8.

I'm trying to write an efficient algorithm that can fill in an additional field in the object, called ParentId, which defines the relation parent-children, to have something like this:

```
id    |  Code         |   ParentId
1        10 15            NULL
2        10 15 10         1
3        10 15 20         1
4        10 15 30         1
5        10 15 30 10      4
6        10 15 30 20      4
7        10 20            NULL
8        10 20 30         7
9        10 20 30 40      8
```

The list could contain up to 10000 objects, so it's quite large.
I'd like to avoid parsing the Code field as it could slow down a lot the loop.
Is there an alternative way?

Comment: Why don't you make the code field int[] instead of a string?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public class MyObject
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Code { get; set; }
}
public class Result
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Code { get; set; }
    public int? ParentId { get; set; }
}
```

```
var source = new List<MyObject> {
    new MyObject { Id = 1, Code = "10 15" },
    new MyObject { Id = 2, Code = "10 15 10" },
    new MyObject { Id = 3, Code = "10 15 20" },
    new MyObject { Id = 4, Code = "10 15 30" },
    new MyObject { Id = 5, Code = "10 15 30 10" },
    new MyObject { Id = 6, Code = "10 15 30 20" },
    new MyObject { Id = 7, Code = "10 20" },
    new MyObject { Id = 8, Code = "10 20 30" },
    new MyObject { Id = 9, Code = "10 20 30 40" }
};
```

```
var result = new List<Result>(source.Count);
result.Add(new Result { Id = source[0].Id, Code = source[0].Code, ParentId = null });

for (int i = 1; i < source.Count; i++)
{
    var cur = source[i];

    if (cur.Code.Length < source[i - 1].Code.Length)
    {
        result.Add(new Result { Id = cur.Id, Code = cur.Code, ParentId = null });
        continue;
    }

    for (int j = i - 1; j >= 0; j--)
    {
        if (cur.Code.StartsWith(source[j].Code))
        {
            result.Add(new Result { Id = cur.Id, Code = cur.Code, ParentId = source[j].Id });
            break;
        }
    }
}

foreach (var x in result)
    Console.WriteLine($"{x.Id}  {x.Code,-12}  {x.ParentId?.ToString() ?? "NULL"}");
```